# SIlverlight encode PCM for uploading

Tags: silverlight, audio, encoding

I've developed a recorder in Silverlight and I was able to upload wave/PCM. A recorded audio of 20 seconds is about 3 Mb which is a lot. Is there any library available to encode wave/PCM to minimize file size?

I was looking for some library to encode into mp3 format, but those are not available for Silverlight applications due to requirement of native support.

What is normally done in this case?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options: do encoding in managed code or use interop with native code (i.e. COM automation for SL4, P/Invoke for SL5). For managed solution you can write your own compression, ADPCM for exaple is very simple and will give 4:1 compression ratio. Check out these too: http://cspeex.codeplex.com/, http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=74242. You can also find commertial managed encoder if you willing to spend few hundred bucks on the license.